# If something is $2^{N+1}$, how can I get $N$ back from the end result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need this for a GIF encoder I'm programming, if something is  $2^{N+1}$, how can I get $N$ back from the end result?

For example, $2^{7+1} = 256$, how can I get back to $7$ from $256$?

I've spent over an hour with a pencil and a sheet of paper trying to remember how to "balance equations" from my time in college but i cant seem to remember...

This seems pretty basic for this site but i was pushed here from stack overflow because it "wasn't programming related.."

Hopefully I'm not posting out of place here either

Comment: $\log_2(x)-1$ should do the job. If you don't have $\log_2$ function in your calculator, then you can use $\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}-1$ instead.

Comment: Don't worry, this site is for math questions at all levels.

Comment: Yes, Regret's answer works for logs to any base. If logs to the base $2$ are available, then the formula simplifies because then $\log2=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2^{n+1}=x\\
\log(2^{n+1})=\log(x)\\
(n+1)\log(2)=\log(x)\\
n=\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}-1\\
$$

In mathematics, just "$\log$" usually means with base $e$, but it does not matter which base you use here. This is because $\frac{\log_a(x)}{\log_a(2)}$ is the same number for any base $a$, it is equal to $\log_2(x)$. If you have access to base $2$ logarithm, you can just use $\log_2(x)-1$. If you only have access to a logarithm with a different base, you can use $\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}-1$.

---

You should be careful if you are using floating point numbers, however. For example,

`Math.log(Math.pow(2, 31))/Math.log(2)`

in JavaScript results in `31.000000000000004` and not $31$ like it should if floats were accurate.

Comment: @James: I added a small detail to the end, do you think it is relevant?

Comment: dont _think_ this should be an issue. After getting the number I do round up which in the case of what you said a size of 31 would come out as 32, but it only wastes a byte of data so I'm not worried about it. Thanks anyway good to know if random values show up and I cant understand why.